# Vue-router change mode at runtime

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I instantiate the vue-router with option:

```
mode: "abstract"
```

After that, i want to change the route at runtime:

```
this.$router.mode = 'hash';
```

Then I navigate:

```
this.$router.push({name: 'test'});
```

And there is no hash in the URL.

So how can I change the mode at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the mode doesn't do anything while the mode is only used in the constructor of VueRouter. With the mode VueRouter executes the following code (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/index.js):

```
switch (mode) {
  case 'history':
    this.history = new HTML5History(this, options.base)
    break
  case 'hash':
    this.history = new HashHistory(this, options.base, this.fallback)
    break
  case 'abstract':
    this.history = new AbstractHistory(this, options.base)
    break
  default:
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      assert(false, `invalid mode: ${mode}`)
    }
}
```

But basically it's better to recreate your VueRouter

Answer (score -1):

So, why don't you initiate it using `mode: "hash"`?

Comment: Because the behavior of the app should be like this. So i need to change the mode dynamiclly

Comment: prefer history but have to use hash because browser compatibility.